# Calculate refractive index

Tags: homework-and-exercises, refraction, wavelength, dispersion

Is it possible to calculate the refractive index of a material for $wavelength = 546.07 \ nm$, knowing that the dispersion of a prism made of this material is $3.44 \times 10^{-5} \ nm^{-1}$, and that the refractive index for the yellow line, $577.96 \ nm$ wavelength, is $1.5171$ ?

Comment: try this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations

Comment: @AslanMonahov This is not about the Fresnel equation, it is about the definition of the coefficient of dispersion.

Comment: Hint: The index of refraction is a function of the wavelength $n(\lambda)$, the (coefficient of) dispersion is given by $\frac{dn}{d\lambda}$. Now you can Taylor expand $n(\lambda)$ to the first order to approximate $n(\lambda + \Delta \lambda)$. Note that it should say, that the dispersion *at a wavelength* has a certain value – the dispersion is typically not constant.